# osm map loading error

Tags: android, osmdroid

i want to view map in openstreetmap. i added osmdroid-android-3.0.8 and slf4j-android-1.5.8 and i gave following permissions...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

my code........

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapview=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapview.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapcontroller=mapview.getController();
    mapcontroller.setZoom(13);
    GeoPoint gp=new GeoPoint(51500000, -150000);
    mapcontroller.setCenter(gp);
}
```

but i get empty map and get a error in LogCat....

Error downloading MapTile.
java.lang.SequrityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10034 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_...

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2):

//you need to add this use permission in your manifest

// and make sure you are running that in google api

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```